# How is binary search faster than linear search?

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, linear-search

We need a sorted array to perform a binary search. In that case, the time complexity is already greater than the linear search, so isn't linear search a better option in that case?

Comment: If you need to sort once then search many times, the cost of sorting is amortized over many searches.

Comment: Because sorting is not a part of binary search but a requirement for data. So for single lookup sort + binary search maybe slower than a linear search but that a different story than comparing one search with another.

Comment: A mathematician friend once said to me "Well, log n is effectively a constant for large n!"  In other words, O(n log n) is not much worse than O(n) in practical terms for a single search, which makes it very worthwhile as a hedge against the need to do multiple additional searches.

Comment: Note that "sorted" is a property of the elements and does not imply that the array has *been* sorted. For instance `int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};` defines a sorted array.

Answer (score 3):

A linear search runs in `O(N)` time, because it scans through the array from start to end.

On the other hand, a binary search first sorts the array in `O(NlogN)` time (if it is not already sorted), then performs lookups in `O(logN)` time.

For a small number of lookups, using a linear search *would* be faster than using binary search. However, whenever the number of lookups is greater than `logN`, binary search will theoretically have the upper hand in performance.

So, the answer to your question is: Linear search and binary search perform lookups in different ways. Linear search scans through the whole array, while binary search sorts the array first. These two search techniques have **differing time complexities**, but that does not mean that one will *always* be better than the other.

Specifically, linear search works well when the size of the list is small and/or you only need to perform a small number of lookups. Binary search should perform better in all other situations.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be better if your container is sorted already or if you want to search for many values.

Answer (score 1):

First of all for Binary Search the precondition is that the array is sorted, which means you do not need to resort it. Secondly if you are talking about integer arrays, you can use RadixSort O(d*n) or CountingSort O(n+l) which are similar to linear search in terms of complexity....

Answer (score 0):

Binary search is faster than linear when the given array is already sorted.

For a sorted array, binary search offers an average O(log n) meanwhile linear offers O(n).

For any given array that is not sorted, linear search becomes best since O(n) is better than sorting the array ( using quicksort for example O(n log n) ) and then applying binary search after that, thus given O(n log n + log n) complexity.

Comment: Actually if it is just integers you can do radixSort which is O(d*k) which is similar in complexity to linear search.